# Sharepoint com Angular. Estamos fazendo certo? Qual a melhora forma de integrar?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

Olá,
Aqui na empresa temos o Sharepoint 2013 com Angular.
Cheguei depois do projeto iniciar.

Bom,
Aqui eles usam as Web Parts para cuspir tags angular nas páginas.
E a partir daí temos toda a execução no Angular e não no Sharepoint Web Parts sabe.

Como não passei por isto antes, seria por aí mesmo a união do Sharepoint ao Angular?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de implementar uma aplicação é utilizando as metodologias e práticas que a equipe já possui e está confortável com.

Isso dito, [o Sharepoint 2013 possui uma interface REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx). Seria interessante neste caso utilizar esta interface para implementar soluções com uma melhor divisão de camadas - onde o Angular é responsável pelo aspecto SPA e o Sharepoint pelo backend.

Answer (score 0):

Este meio de desenvolvimento é bastante promissor por conta da separação das camadas back-end e front-end. 
A própria Microsoft incentiva este tipo de desenvolvimento e como o Sharepoint tem uma API REST. Além da API REST o Sharepoint conta com o CSOM.

No sharepoint on-line este é o melhor caminho de desenvolvimento já que você perder o poder de customizar o back-end, diferente do on-premisse.